# How to get Style of a document (word) with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have a document (MS Word) and I applied the "Line (Distincive)" style to it. Now I want to get the name of Style in this document (Line Distincive) with using C#. I don't know how to solve this problem. This is my code.

[image]

```
    void ApplyStyleDocument()
    {
        object w;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _activeDoc;
        try
        {
             w = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
            w = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)w;
       _activeDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument;
       MessageBox.Show(_activeDoc.Styles.GetType().Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: does your code error out & what is the output of MessageBox ?

Comment: I want the output is "Line (Distincive)". But my code has just give the result "--COMObject"

Comment: The `Document` object returns a collection of all the styles in a document. For a specific style name you need to reference an object that is formatted with a style. That could be a selection or any "range" of contiguous text. Since you don't specify what it is you want the style of, it's not possible to say any more than that.

Comment: Interested to know if you found any solution for this, if yes please post it as answer thanks

Comment: I'm going to check the format of Heading and normal paragraph in Line (Distincive) style. I will solve the problem like the way Cindy posted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the style from the `ParagraphProperties` like so:

```
var style = paragraph.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val.Value;
```

Comment: A style or other formatting can be applied to things other than a paragraph. Without knowing what the OP actually needs, it's not really possible to answer this question... And anyway, this looks more like Open XML SDK and not "interop" code so is not applicable, here.